# PHP Recursive Descent Recognizer - Not Working

Tags: php, parsing, recursion

Ok I'm trying to get my PHP RDR working and when I access the PHP form from the HTML file I don't get any output. For example, I don't receive the echo "Grammer is valid/invalid". The echo at the beginning works letting me know that my html is correctly accessing the form, but then it's blank after that. The input comes in correctly right at the beginning, but I believe there is an error calling my functions. It's mostly done, so it shouldn't take too much effort to get working. A valid grammar test for input that I'm using is 225$. Any advice is appreciated.
Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="rdrTest2.php" method="post">
Enter string: <input type="text" name="userInput"><br><br>
<input type ="submit" value ="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
/**
* Grammar class
* The Grammar class is a main/top level class for parsing a string
* and matching it to a grammar.
* grammar rules will be implemented in to another class which will extend this basic class
*/

echo "PHP Form Accessed.<br>";
$input = $_POST["userInput"];

abstract class Grammar{
    // User input - string
    protected $inputString;
    //Pointer pointing to current position in input string
    protected $pointerInString;
    // boolean variable which will return true or false based on parsing result
    protected $resultString;
    //end of string variable '$ - in this case'.
    protected $endOfString;

    /**
    * Recursive Descent Parser
    * This function will get overridden by child classes
    */
    abstract protected function exp();

    function __construct($input, $delimiter = '$') {
        $this->inputString = $input; // user input string taken from input page
        $this->pointerInString = 0; // initial pointer value will be 0 - pointer pointing to first character in input string
        $this->resultString = true; // it will be set to false if program can not match string to the expected at any point in time while execution
        $this->endOfString = $delimiter;
        $this->exp(); // starting point for each parsing
        if(!$this->endOfInput())
        $this->resultString = false; // this means the string contains some unparsable character
    }
    /*
    * True if expression is resultString else False
    */
    function isresultString() {
        return $this->resultString;
    }

    /*
    */
    protected function endOfInput() {
        // check for end of the string
        $isDone = ($this->pointerInString >= strlen($this->inputString)) || (strlen($this->inputString) == 0);
        if($this->pointerInString == (strlen($this->inputString) - 1)) {
            if($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString] == $this->endOfString) {
                $isDone = true;
                echo "Grammar is valid.";
            }
            return $isDone;
        }
    }
    /*
    * match function basically matches character with current pointer character
    * if matches, it will advance pointer to next character and return true.
    */
    protected function match($myToken) {
        if(($this->pointerInString < strlen($this->inputString)) &&
        ($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString] == $myToken))
        {
            $this->pointerInString += 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
}

/**
* Grammar for RDR4 is:
* EXP ::= + NUM | -NUM | NUM
* NUM ::= NUM DIGIT | DIGIT
* DIGIT ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
* Assume the input ends with '$'.
*/

class RDR4 extends Grammar {
    function exp() {
        if($this->endOfInput())
        {
            $this->resultString = false;
            echo "Grammar is invalid.";
        }
        else
        {
            if($this->resultString)
            {
                if(($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString] == '+') || ($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString] == '-'))
                {
                    $this->match($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString]);
                }
                $this->num();
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    * handle processing for the term rule in the grammar
    * handle processing for the factor
    */
    function num() {
        $this->digit();
        while($this->resultString && !$this->endOfInput())
        $this->digit();
    }
    /*
    * If the character at the current position is in [0..3]
    * advance the position pointer else change resultString to false.
    */
    function digit() {
        $digitArray = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
        if($this->endOfInput()) {
            $this->resultString = false;
            echo "Grammar is invalid.";
        }
        elseif(array_search($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString], $digitArray) !== False)
        {
            $this->resultString = $this->resultString && $this->match($this->inputString[$this->pointerInString]);
        }
        else{
            $this->resultString = false;
            echo "Grammar is invalid.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use: `new RDR4($input)` and then execute it?

Comment: That could be the problem. I can't figure out how to call the functions and use the input from the HTML file. If I put RDR4($input); on the last line I get a Fatal error stating a call to undefined RDR4().

Comment: Immediately after your `$input = $_POST["userInput"];` add something like: _`$parser = new  RDR4($input);`_

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to cal the `exp()` function from inside the 'constructor'. However, it should be ok.

Comment: That was my problem! I believe this is because RDR4 is extension of  grammar class which is an object that needed to be created. So silly I don't remember my junior college CS courses! Thank you Ryan! If you submit official answer I will give you credit!

Comment: I suggest that you post an answer explaining the issue and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ryan's comments I was able to discover my problem. Class RDR4 is an extension of class Grammar and needs to be created. I created the object with the line $parser = new RDR4($input); just after $input = $_POST["input"]; at the beginning of the PHP form. This solved my problem and the call to the functions now works. Thank you again Ryan!